# SQLite dummy value in select output on empty table

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database with this sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE PROVA 
(
    c1 TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    c2 TEXT NOT NULL,
    c3 TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

This table will be empty at certain times (e.g. during initialization) and I need a query which can return an output like this without having to specify the columns name (a dummy value for every column).

```
c1        c2        c3
--------  --------  --------
dummy     dummy     dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use a union trick here with the help of `RANK`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c1, c2, c3, 1 AS pos FROM PROVA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'dummy', 'dummy', 'dummy', 2
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT c1, c2, c3, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY pos) rn
    FROM cte
)

SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: the table column may be variable and I cannot specify it in the select statement

Comment: Then there may not be any way to satisfy your requirement.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of because before I applied I did some research.
Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: @Tom The biggest problem is that your table doesn't actually have a `dummy` row.  So the first CTE in my answer, in some form, is basically unavoidable.  There might be more than one to proceed once you have generated the dummy data.

Comment: when I run my program for the first time the table may be empty and I have to handle this

Comment: ...we're going in circles now, then use my answer